# Как удалить в Excel все данные которые повторяются больше или меньше 2 раз?

Tags: excel, vba

Как удалить все данные в таблице экселя, которые есть более 1 раза, но менее 3?

Поясню, вот пример данных.
1
2
3
2
3
2
После удаления, необходимо, что бы осталить только 3. так как они встречаються только два раза.

Пример такой, только данных 30 тысяч. Нужно чтоб остались только те, котрые повторяются 2 раза.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После уделения, должно быть вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А пример показать? Можно с помощью формулы и фильтра, можно макросом. Но Вам покажут решение, а окажется, что данные не так расположены, а вот это нужно не туда, а то перевернуть... Где размещать результат? Или удалять на месте?

Comment: Сляпать доп. столбец со СЧЕТЕСЛИ(), фильтр по нему - все значения, кроме 2, да и удалить всё оставшееся. Для "схлопывания" пустых строк - отсортировать в любом направлении.

Comment: @vikttur есть таблица, более 30к записей. 4 столбца. Первый это айди. К сожелению нужно сделать в Excel 2007, иначебы просто использовал повер квери. И так айди обозначают людей. Некоторые приходили 1 раз, некоторые 10. Все разбросанно. Нужно отфильтровать данные так, что бы остались только те, кто приходил 2 раза.

Comment: При таком количестве лучше работать с *VBA*. Хотя, если разово, то действуйте по подсказке *Akina*. Отфильтровать на месте? Удалить ненужные? Поместить результат на другом листе?===== *1 2 3 2 3 2 После удаления, необходимо, что бы осталить только 3* - как это у Вас получилось? Не может быть нечетное количество строк. Или Вы что-то не договариваете.

Comment: @vikttur Да, лучше с VBA, но втретился с VB впервые и пока сообразить не могу как написать. пример прикрепил к вопросу

Comment: Отвечаете выборочно...

Comment: @vikttur потомчу, что я не понимаю, как ответить. Мне просто нужно удалить все данные которые повторяються более двух раз или всего один. Все. Нечего дополнительного не нужно.

Comment: Вы внимательно читайте вопросы. Как выводить результат? На картинке ID 678. В результат помещать две строки или одну?

Comment: @vikttur Я извиняюсь. прикрепил, как должно выглядеть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаляем лишнее на месте. Используем функцию листа. Работает медленнее, чем на массивах, но код проще.

```
Sub DelRepeats()
Dim rRng As Range, rDel As Range
Dim lRw As Long, i As Long
Const lRepeat As Long = 2 ' требуемое кол-во повторов'

    With ActiveSheet ' если нужно, указать другой лист'
        lRw = .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row: If lRw < 2 Then Exit Sub
        Set rRng = .Range("A1:D" & lRw)

        For i = 2 To lRw ' если шапки нет, начинать со строки 1'
            If Application.CountIf(rRng, rRng(i, 1).Value) <> lRepeat Then
                If rDel Is Nothing Then
                    Set rDel = .Cells(i, 1)
                Else
                    Set rDel = Union(rDel, .Cells(i, 1))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End With

    If Not rDel Is Nothing Then rDel.EntireRow.Delete
    Set rRng = Nothing: Set rDel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Отсортировать, если нужно (или исходные данные, или после обработки).

Количество повторов задается константой *lRepeat*. Если количество нужно больше/меньше, изменить знаки в строке условия подсчета. Например, для того, чтобы оставить строки меньше, нужно удалять строки с количеством *>=*:

```
If Application.CountIf(rRng, rRng(i, 1).Value) >= lRepeat Then
```

Comment: при таком изменнении из записи 
d
e
c
c
a
b
b
c
a
a
b
c
a
c
остаеться только 
d
e

когда нужно 
d
e
b
b
c
a
a
b
c
a
c

Comment: Вы внимательно читайте: *Например, для того, чтобы* **оставить строки меньше** . Если нужно другое, разберитесь со знаками

Comment: По итогу у меня не получается, я понимаю в знаках (меньше или равно) и тд. Просто не догоняю как остальное изменить, что бы подходил этот изменненый алгоритм. Он в не удаляеет лишние повторения, а только указывает те где нету их. 
А так же у вас в профиле, было бы отлично если бы был указан еще и пайпал.

Comment: Извините, не так понял. Удаление лишних повторений - это другой вопрос.

Comment: Наверно не стоило тогда удалять предыдущий вопрос. Заного опубликовать? или тут возможно?

Comment: Да, я неправильно понял. Вопрос другой

Answer (score 1):

Вот записанный, в принципе без корректировки, макрос, преобразующий на месте исходную таблицу (A1:D7) в конечную (A1:D2):

```
Sub Макрос1()
'
' Макрос1 Макрос
'

'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[1],RC[1])"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A7")
    Range("A1:A7").Select
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$8").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=1", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=3"
    Rows("2:7").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Columns("A:E").Select
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Лист1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Лист1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), _
        SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Лист1").Sort
        .SetRange Range("A1:E8")
        .Header = xlNo
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Вот он же, поправленный, сам определяет диапазон для работы:

```
Sub Macros1()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim length As Long
length = sht.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIF(C[1],RC[1])"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:A" & length)
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
length = length + 1
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$E$" & length).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="<>2"
Rows("2:" & length).Select
Selection.ClearContents
Rows("1:1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Columns("A:E").Select
sht.Sort.SortFields.Clear
sht.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A1"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With sht.Sort
    .SetRange Range("A1:E" & length)
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
End Sub
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает. Буду разбираться дальше сам в VBA.